# Private functions in Object-Oriented JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

When I'm trying to do object-oriented pure JS with private methods, I frequently do the following

```
(function(exports) {

  var Foo = function(num) {
    this.num = num
  };

  var addTwo = function() {
    this.num += 2;
  };

  Foo.prototype.addFour = function() {
   addTwo.call(this);
   addTwo.call(this);
  };

  exports.Foo = Foo;

})(this);
```

Then I can do

```
var foo = new Foo(0);
foo.addFour();
console.log(foo.num); // => 4
```

It feels clean and it allows me to create truly private functions, rather than using a `_` prefix to denote that a method should be treated as private (but actually isn't).

This allows me to know which functions I need to unit test and which I don't. It also prevents me from being tempted to use functions that should be private. But I don't see this pattern elsewhere.

So why don't others use this pattern and what do they do instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plenty of people do that. It is somewhat formally known as the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/).

---

**Advantages**

- Cleaner approach for developers
- Supports private data
- Less clutter in the global namespace
- Localization of functions and variables through closures
- The syntax of our scripts are even more consistent
- Explicitly defined public methods and variables which lead to increased readability

**Disadvantages**

- Private methods are unaccessible.
- Some people say that this leads to the inability of unit testing but more often than not, if you're questioning the integrity of a function, it should probably be engineered in such a fashion that exposes the utility of that function publicly, thus making it testable. Given the adaptation of the module pattern by jQuery and their everyday use of QUnit to automate testing, this bullet point isn't really relevant but still listed for documentation purposes.
- Private methods and functions lose extendability since they are unaccessible (see my comment in the previous bullet point).
- It's harder to patch public methods and variables that are referred to by something private.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access modifiers (private, protected, public) in JavaScript,
but you can create your objects so
that some variables and methods won`t accessed from outside.

```js
var ExampleObject = function() {
  var privateVariable = "I am Private Variable" // this variable can be accessed only in ExampleObject instance;

  this.publicVariable = "I am Public Variable" // this way you can access variable from outside;

  // NOW FOR METHODS

  // this method only could be accessed inside instance of ExampleObject
  var privateFunction = function() {
    return "I am Private Function";
  }

  // this method could be accessed outside and inside instance of ExampleObject
  // also notice that this method can return private variables or functions of instance to outside of instance
  this.publicFunction = function() {
    alert(privateFunction())
    return privateVariable;
  }
}

var instanceExample = new ExampleObject();
<!-- alert(instanceExample.privateFunction()) // will throw Uncaught TypeError: instanceExample.privateFunction is not a function -->

alert(instanceExample.publicFunction())
```